# Upload function works locally but fails after deploying to Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am writing a backend function using the Node.JS Express framework. The function is to upload file to Firebase Storage. This is my controller named fileController.js

```
(function () {
    var router = require('express').Router(),
        middleware = require('../../util/middleware'),
        os = require('os'),
        path = require('path'),
        Busboy = require('busboy'),
        fs = require('fs'),
        UUID = require("uuid-v4");
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');

    router.post('/svc/uploadFile', middleware.isValidUser, functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        const gcconfig = {
            projectId: '****',
            keyFilename: '****'
        }
        const gcs = new Storage(gcconfig);
        if (req.method !== "POST") {
            return res.status(500).json({ message: "Not allowed" });
        }
        const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
        let uploadData = null;
        let uuid = UUID();

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), uuid + filename);
            uploadData = { file: filepath, type: mimetype };
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
        });

        busboy.on('finish', () => {
            const bucket = gcs.bucket('****');
            bucket.upload(uploadData.file, {
                uploadType: 'media',
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: uploadData.type,
                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
                    }
                }
            }).then((data) => {
                let file = data[0];
                return res.status(200).json({ fileLocation: **** });
            }).catch((err) => {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
            });
        });
        return req.pipe(busboy);
    }));
    module.exports = router;
}());
```

This is my index.js file

```
(function () {
    var express = require('express'),
        app = express(),
        bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
        mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        port = 3000,
        cors = require('cors'),
        passport = require('passport'),
        passportCfg = require('./src/config/passport'),
        session = require('express-session'),
        flash = require('connect-flash');

    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
    passportCfg(passport);
    // connect to mongoose
    mongoose.connect('****', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    //Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
    app.use(cors({
        origin: ['httt://localhost:4200', 'http://127.0.0.1:4200'],
        credentials: true
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(session({
        name: '****',
        secret: '****',
        saveUninitialized: false,
        resave: false,
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 3000,
            httpOnly: false,
            secure: false
        },
        store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
    }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    app.use(flash());
    app.use(require('./src/controller/fileController'));
    app.listen(port);
    console.log('Running on port:' + port);
    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
}());
```

This is dependency in package.json file

```
 "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "*",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "*",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "http-status": "^1.4.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.4",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^2.4.2",
    "busboy": "^0.3.0",
    "child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
    "os": "^0.1.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "uuid-v4": "^0.1.0"
  }
```

I install **firebase-tools** then run locally first doing **firebase serve** command and it run perfectly fine in local. Then I deploy to firebase using command **firebase deploy** with node engine 8.

Locally, **busboy.on('file')** will be invoked and set up the variable **uploadData** first, then **busboy.on('finish')** will use it inside. But in Google Firebase, inside the event **busboy.on('finish')** the **uploadData** is always undefined.

Is this because of the stateless property of the `REST` service?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your code.  I don't think you can't pass a cloud functions definition to an express route. You're supposed to export your function definition from index.js so Cloud Functions knows its an endpoint.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes I can. I have everything up and run now except that upload function. All you need to do is some thing like this:   
    app.use(require('./src/controller/yourController'));
    app.listen(port);
    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

Comment: How are you running this?  Are you even deploying to Cloud Functions?  If not, then you shouldn't need firebase-functions at all.  The only use for that module is for code deployed to Cloud Functions using the Firebase CLI.

Comment: @DougStevenson You can config like this and then deploy:   const functions = require('firebase-functions');    app.use(require('./src/controller/yourController'));
    app.listen(port);    exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  That doesn't really answer my questions.  Please edit the question to be more clear about how you are deploying and running this code.  If you're not deploying to Cloud Functions, then you just don't need firebase-functions at all.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry i think it was my bad that I didn't distinguish clearly between Google Cloud Functions and Firebase before asking. I  meant I deployed my express to Firebase not Google Cloud Functions and got that problem.

Comment: Could you still edit your question to answer my questions?  It's still not clear how exactly you are deploying and running this code. List out the exact steps.  Also, you should know that if you're deploying functions using the Firebase CLI, it is still deploying to the product called Cloud Functions.  It's the same product, different tools.

Comment: @DougStevenson I just updated my questions. Please take a look again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue. Thanks to every one in this thread 
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/411 especially the comment of https://github.com/serhiipalash

```
const cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const Busboy = require('busboy')
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')
const contentType = require('content-type')

app.post(
  '/post-tweet',
  [
    // middlewares

    cors({ origin: true }),

    bodyParser.json(),

    bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true,
    }),

    (req, res, next) => {
      if (
        req.rawBody === undefined &&
        req.method === 'POST' &&
        req.headers['content-type'].startsWith('multipart/form-data')
      ) {
        getRawBody(
          req,
          {
            length: req.headers['content-length'],
            limit: '10mb',
            encoding: contentType.parse(req).parameters.charset,
          },
          function(err, string) {
            if (err) return next(err)
            req.rawBody = string
            next()
          }
        )
      } else {
        next()
      }
    },

    (req, res, next) => {
      if (
        req.method === 'POST' &&
        req.headers['content-type'].startsWith('multipart/form-data')
      ) {
        const busboy = new Busboy({
          headers: req.headers,
        })

        var fileBuffer = new Buffer('')

        busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
          file.on('data', data => {
            fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, data])
          })

          file.on('end', () => {
            const file_object = {
              fieldname,
              originalname: filename,
              encoding,
              mimetype,
              buffer: fileBuffer,
            }

            req.file = file_object
          })
        })

        req.data = {}

        busboy.on('field', function(
          fieldname,
          val
          // fieldnameTruncated
          // valTruncated
          // encoding
          // mimetype
        ) {
          req.data[fieldname] = val
        })

        busboy.on('finish', function() {
          console.log('Done parsing form!')

          next()
        })

        busboy.end(req.rawBody)
      } else {
        next()
      }
    },
  ],
  function(req, res, next) {
    // request handler
    const file = req.file

    console.log(file)
  }
)
```

Comment: this is the link to the comment https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/411#issuecomment-408659948